# Not every EKEvent shows up in Calendar after saving multiple events

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, calendar, eventkit

I'm inserting events into my Calendar, and just saw that not every event gets saved.

One day I should have 3 events saved, but only the first and the last shows up in the calendar. I've printed the results, no error occurs when I save the events in the eventStore.

Steps:
Have a loop creating EKEvents and saving them in the EventStore with commit:false, then after finished call commit() on the EventStore.

I get no errors, but missing some events in the Calendar, any ideas how to find the source of this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it looks random to me but there must be a reason that I wasn’t able to find :/